# Why UNION SELECT gives you the number of columns in SQLI

Tags: select, web-applications, union, sql-injection

I am trying to figure out why one can figure out the number of columns from using 'union SELECT'

For example, if you have a webpage http://www.vulnerable-site.com/index.php?firstArg=1 
I learned that you can put

http://www.vulnerable-site.com/index.php?firstArg=1 union SELECT 1,2,3,4 --

to find out the number of columns in the table. Basically, you keep adding numbers to till you stop getting errors. Why is that?

Can anyone please help me with this basic question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that the number of columns on both sides of the UNION statement must match. So, this command can be used to find out the number of columns in a table.

Answer (score 0):

UNION keyword can be used to retrieve data from other tables within the database. This results in an SQL injection UNION attack. so Determining the number of columns required in an SQL injection UNION attack. there are two effective methods to determine how many columns are being returned from the original query. "ORDER BY" and "UNION SELECT"